# Local classes : C++03 vs. C++11

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, local-class

Is there any change in the usage of local class in C++11?

It seems in C++03 local classes cannot be used as template argument (I recall that).

Consider this code,

```
template<typename T> void f(const T&) {}

//Note : S is a local class defined inside main()
int main() { struct S{};  f(S()); } //I want template argument to be deduced.
```

But it gives compilation error (C++03 mode), saying ([ideone](http://ideone.com/6nB1U)):

> prog.cpp:4: error: no matching function for call to ‘f(main()::S)’

However, it compiles fine when compiling it in C++11 mode ([ideone](http://ideone.com/oNkWE)), which makes sense to me, otherwise lambda wouldn't work. So I guess that there is at least this change in the usage of local classes. Am I right? What are other changes concerning local classes?

Please quote the relevant text from the Standards (C++03 and C++11 both) so readers can compare themselves, and for future reference.

Comment: At least in older C++ standards you could not instantiate templates using local types.

Comment: I distinctly remember this as a change from C++03 to C++11. The restriction local classes vs templates was more arbitrary than anything and I am not sure that it eased the writing of compilers (removing the local concepts *would* ease it, once you parsed them though, what's to gain ?). I don't have the C++03 Standard though, so you'll have to take my word for it until someone comes that has it.

Comment: There was a [paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2003/n1427.pdf) about this.

Comment: @Mankarse: Thanks. That looks quite interesting. Will read it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The differences are visible by comparing §14.3.1/2 in both standards.

- C++03

  > A local type, a type with no linkage, an unnamed type or a type compounded from any of these types shall
  >   not be used as a template-argument for a template type-parameter. [Example:

  ```
  template <class T> class X { /* ... */ };
  void f()
  {
   struct S { /* ... */ };
   X<S> x3;        // error: local type used as template-argument
   X<S*> x4;        // error: pointer to local type used as template-argument
  }
  ```

  > —end example] [Note: a template type argument may be an incomplete type (3.9). ]
- C++0x (n3290)

  > [ Example:

  ```
  template <class T> class X { };
  template <class T> void f(T t) { }
  struct { } unnamed_obj;

  void f() {
   struct A { };
   enum { e1 };
   typedef struct { } B;
   B b;
   X<A> x1;        // OK
   X<A*> x2;       // OK
   X<B> x3;        // OK
   f(e1);          // OK
   f(unnamed_obj); // OK
   f(b);           // OK
  }
  ```

  > — end example ] [ Note: A template type argument may be an incomplete type (3.9). — end note ]

C++03 explicitly disallows local classes in template type arguments. C++11 doesn't, and even includes an example of a valid use of such.

Answer (score 10):

From older standard:

> (14.3) A local type, a type with no linkage, an unnamed type or a type compounded from any of these types shall not be used as a template-argument for a template type-parameter.

It seems to be removed in the C++11 standard.

More restrictions:

> (9.8) Declarations in a local class can
>   use only type names, static variables, extern variables and functions, and enumerators from the enclosing
>   scope.
>
> (9.8) A local class shall not have member templates.
>
> (14.5.4) A friend template shall not be declared in a local class.
>
> (9.4.2 ) A local class shall not have static data members.
>
> (9.3) Member functions of a local class (9.8) have no linkage.

Comment: Are there any reasons for the rest of the restrictions that were not lifted from local classes?

Comment: "A local class shall not have member templates" is in 14.5.2. "A local class shall not have static data members" is in 9.8. Just to clarify, all these restrictions remain in C++11.

Answer (score 2):

According to [my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991062/passing-unnamed-classes-through-functions) the limitation is removed and local classes can be used as template arguments.
I see no reference to the new standard though.