# Equivalancy of using typedef and an anonymous class definition to conventional class definition

Tags: c++, typedef, anonymous-class

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between ‘struct’ and ‘typedef struct’ in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612328/difference-between-struct-and-typedef-struct-in-c)

An answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13138605/why-class-int-i-is-not-fully-standard-conformant) led me to wonder about the following:

I presume that defining a class as follows:

```
typedef class {int i;} C;
```

would be completely equivalent to defining it in the conventional manner:

```
class C
{
   int i;
};
```

Is this presumption correct?

Comment: @ecatmur I guess it is (apart from the negligible class versus struct difference).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this isolated example they are functionally the same, at least from the outside.

However there are differences.  One instance in particular, you cannot declare a constructor for a `struct` or a `class` declared in this way, simply because the `class` is unnamed.  Similarly you cannot declare any function that involves the class' name.  Here are some examples:

```
typedef class
{
public:
  Gizmo() : n_(42) {}; // NOT OK
  ~Gizmo();
  Gizmo& operator<<(int n);    
private:
  int n_;
} Gizmo;
```

You also cannot forward declare an anonymous class:

```
class Gizmo;
```

In C++ I have never seen a case where `typedef`ing an anonymous `struct` or a `class` is preferable to simply declaring a `class` or a `struct` that is named.  In some cases the traditional method is definitely preferred.  The moral of the story is:  don't use `typedef class {} Name;` in C++.  It buys you nothing, and costs you something.

Comment: "you cannot declare a constructor" -- or destructor, copy-/move-assignment operator or anything that involves the classes name, obviously.

Comment: `typedef struct { ... } name` is mostly seen in code that must retain binary compatibility with pre - C'99 libraries, where the type space and tag space where distinct. (for example, win32 API or X11 API)

Comment: One thing you, interestingly, *can* do is define member functions out-of-class, since you're allowed to use a typedef-name for the class-name here. See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9146167/500104).

Comment: Although there are other good / correct answers I'm accepting this one because I should have seen the whole "anonymous definition means that things needing the name wont work" aspect.

Comment: One thing it does buy you, is that it prevents anyone naming a function `Name` (which could unintentionally interfere with attempts to construct a temporary using `Name()`). See Pubby's answer. But the advice not to use `typedef class {} Name;` is still sound, since if you want that feature you can get it by `typedef class Name {} Name;`

Answer (score 2):

From a practical standpoint yes, because the standard says (9.1/5) that

> A typedef-name (7.1.3) that names a class type, or a cv-qualified version thereof, is also > a class-name. If a typedef-name that names a cv-qualified class type is used where a
>   class-name is required, the cv-qualifiers are ignored.

7.1/3 says:

> A name declared with the typedef specifier becomes a typedef-name.
>   Within the scope of its declaration, a typedef-name is syntactically
>   equivalent to a keyword and names the type associated with the
>   identifier in the way described in Clause 8. A typedef-name is thus a
>   synonym for another type.

From a theoretical standpoint no, because you could (and indeed I see people already have) draft programs that are valid or invalid depending on which version was used, since 7.1/3 continues from where I cut it off to say:

> A typedef-name does
>   not introduce a new type the way a class declaration (9.1) or enum declaration does.

Comment: So yes in this case, no in general. +1 for showing me from the standard.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a duplicate question (can't find), but if not, observe that this compiles:

```
class C
{
   int i;
};
void C() {}

class C x;
```

while this won't:

```
typedef class
{
   int i;
} C;
void C() {}

C x;
```

The name spaces are different.

Comment: You're right the latter doesn't compile and they do seem to occupy different namespaces, cool. +1 for showing me that you can have a class and a function sharing the same name (its just something I'd subconsciously avoided doing).

Answer (score 0):

They're not equivalent. In particular,

```
int main()
{
    class C c;
}
```

will only compile for one of the two definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is yet another difference: the latter can be forward-declared, the former can't.