# C++ Unnamed Classes

Tags: c++

I have been exploring more C++ and encountered a phenomenon like Unnamed classes.

```
  class : public classB{
        public:
        protected:
        private:
  };
```

How are these classes useful? Is it like the concept of lambda functions?

I would like to know the purpose of such classes. The other threads don't really show any usefulness of the feature.

Comment: Another good post about it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/991062/passing-unnamed-classes-through-functions

Comment: That thread doesn't help me understand it.

Comment: Unnamed structs existed in C. Consider `struct Foo { int d; };`, in C you could not say `Foo x;`, you had to `struct Foo x;`. Then you saw code like `struct Foo { int d; }; typedef struct Foo Foo;` which allows both uses. Or `typedef struct Foo { int d; } Foo;` which is the same. And if you only need the short form, `typedef struct { int d; } Foo;` is enough. And if you only want a variable to use its members directly and never need the type name, `struct { int d; } x = { 42 }; printf("%d\n", x.d);` is allowed.